# SN74HC165 shift register not communicating properly with a Wemos D1 Mini

Tags: esp8266, shift-register

I have a simple circuit with two daisy chained SN74HC165 shift register to collect the input of 9 (for now, for thesting purposes, there are only 2) [TRCT5000](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/H6d009d60a14d484fa535c02e03e1dedfV.jpg_640x640Q90.jpg_.webp) infrared sensors.

## Problems:

I'm encountering the following problems:

1. The output provided by the Wemos D1 Mini does not match the state of the digital inputs of the two SN74HC165. More specifically, when TRCT5000/1 is HIGH, the output from the Wemos D1 Mini is HIGH, and that's fine, but when TRCT5000/2 is HIGH, the output is HIGH for both the TRCT5000. Playing around using different input pins of the SN74HC165 yields other results.
2. The circuit is extremely susceptible to interference, when I place my hand too close to the breadboard the inputs of the SN74HC165 are continuously oscillating between HIGH and LOW. I have added a 0.1 μF ceramic capacitor and a 4.7 μF electrolytics capacitor. between GND and VCC as close as possible to the two  SN74HC165, but this didn't really help. I suspect that this is due to the poor connections on the breadboard and the fact that many unused pins of the two SN74HC165 are unused and not grounded.

## Question:

1. Could someone advise me on what am I doing wrong? Is there an order in which inputs should be connected to the two SN74HC165? Why am I getting those weird outputs?
2. Any recommendation for the final circuit design (attached below) to reduce interference?

## Details of the circuit:

The TRCT5000 have a digital output, high when they sense an obstacle, low when there's nothing in front of the sensor.

The cirucit I designed is fairly simple, I attached here a small sketch of the schematic.

Here's how the circuit is wired (component PIN -> component PIN):

- TRCT5000/1 output -> SN74HC165/1 H
- TRCT5000/2 output -> SN74HC165/2 H
- SN74HC165/1 CLK -> SN74HC165/2 CLK -> Wemos D1 Mini GPIO15
- SN74HC165/1 SH/LD -> SN74HC165/2 SH/LD -> Wemos D1 Mini GPIO0
- SN74HC165/1 CLK INH -> SN74HC165/2 CLK INH -> Wemos D1 Mini GPIO13
- SN74HC165/1 Qh -> SN74HC165/2 SER
- SN74HC165/2 Qh -> Wemos D1 Mini GPIO2
- VCC and GND lines are connected to 5V and GND lines of the Wemos D1 Mini
- All other pins are not connected to anything (maybe I will adjust the circuit to put everything unused to ground)

## ESPHome code

Here's the ESPHome code I am using:

```
esphome:
  name: esphome-web-bac396
  friendly_name: Bottle_rack_sensor

esp8266:
  board: d1_mini

# Enable logging
logger:

# Enable Home Assistant API
api:
  encryption:
    key: "key"

ota:


wifi:
  ssid: !secret wifi_ssid
  password: !secret wifi_password

  # Enable fallback hotspot (captive portal) in case wifi connection fails
  ap:
    ssid: "Esphome-Web-Bac396"
    password: "key"

captive_portal:

sn74hc165:
  - id: sn74hc165_hub
    clock_pin: 15
    data_pin: 2
    load_pin: 0
    clock_inhibit_pin: 13
    sr_count: 2

binary_sensor:
  - platform: gpio
    name: "SN74HC165_hub Pin #7"
    pin:
      sn74hc165: sn74hc165_hub
# sn74hc165/2 pin H
      number: 7
      inverted: false
  - platform: gpio
    name: "SN74HC165_hub Pin #14"
    pin:
      sn74hc165: sn74hc165_hub
# sn74hc165/1 pin H
      number: 15
      inverted: false
```

[image: SN74HC165 pinout]
[image: Schematic]

Comment: Are you sure about the GPIO mapping of the D1 Mini? For example, the CLK pins of your HC165 connect to the pin marked "D4" on the D1 Mini. This is not GPIO15 (as mentioned in your code and your question) but GPIO2 according to the documentation of the D1 Mini I've been able to find, for example: [here](https://www.wemos.cc/en/latest/d1/d1_mini.html).

Comment: Yes the pin mapping is correct, I have been using it in several other projects. Writing just the number in ESPHome is referring to the PIN number that you posted in the picture.

Comment: Please provide a schematic that shows all the *actual* connections. Anyway, leaving CMOS inputs floating definitely will lead to problems.

Comment: Ok let me sketch it by hand, it's faster

Comment: @CL. I have added the circuit schematic.

Comment: @user3161330 Isn't \$H\$ (pin 6) an input? I see that you've wired it over to something called `out`. Also, these being HC parts, all inputs should be tied to something -- ground or power. Not so? What about SER inputs? Just asking for now...

Comment: Sorry, I'm editing this comment as I misinterpreted your comment. H is an input, and receives a signal from the OUT pin of the TCRT5000. The out pin of the TCRT5000 is HIGH when you place something in front of the infrared sensor and LOW when there's nothing obstructing the sensor.

Comment: @user3161330 Got it. So you show just two devices providing inputs?

Comment: Exactly, when the project is complete there will be 9 of them.

Comment: @user3161330 Shouldn't the SER input of the other one be tied low or high?

Comment: I'll give it a try, but here (https://docs.wokwi.com/parts/wokwi-74hc165) it says: "Use the DS to daisy-chain multiple 74HC165 units together. Connect DS to the Q7 pin of the previous 74HC165 chip in the chain. You can leave DS disconnected if you don't chain or for the first chip in the chain."

Comment: @user3161330 That may work. But I believe all unused inputs for the HC family should be tied somewhere. Otherwise, they may oscillate and consume unwanted power. I don't use HC parts. (I would use HCT.) So I may be ignorant. But that's what I've read.

Comment: @user3161330 You've mentioned that your hand can impact things. This is what I might imagine as true for HC floating inputs. Anyway, can you just ground all the unused inputs (or tie them high?) That would remove any question there.

Comment: I'll give it a try tonight. I'll also try to use other GPIO pins as those have some peculiarities (see here: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-pinout-reference-gpios/)

Comment: That wiki page is wrong. See https://e2e.ti.com/support/logic-group/logic/f/logic-forum/737694/faq-how-does-a-slow-or-floating-input-affect-a-cmos-device.

Comment: So, I have connected to ground all the unused pins except for Qh' (inverted serial output). I have also changed the GPIO pins: clock_pin: 13, data_pin: 14, 15, clock_inhibit_pin: 12. When the TCRT5000/2 (pin H) is HIGH, the microcontroller reports it HIGH and it is fine. However, when the TCRT5000/1 (pin H) is HIGH, the microcontroller reports pin H of both TCRT5000 as HIGH.
I also added two capacitors (0.1microfarad and 4.7microfarad) and all the interference is gone.

Comment: Ok that's very weird. I have disconnected the 5v pin of the wemos d1 mini from the circuit, and everything work properly how it is supposed to be working. My guess is that the 5v supply (despite it is accepted by the sn74hc165) was the problem, and the 3.3v now supplied makes everything work. My question is: where is the 3.3v coming from?

Comment: Do you use a [TRCT5000](https://www.amazon.de/AZDelivery-TRCT5000-Infrarot-Linien-Folger/dp/B07VP4JDTH?th=1) - where is a link to the datasheet? Or is it a [TCRT5000](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83760/tcrt5000.pdf)? https://www.vishay.com/docs/80107/80107.pdf)?

Comment: It's a TRCT500, sorry about the typo!

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in this circuit design:

1. Non-used input pins are not connected to ground causes interference;
2. Using 5v instead of 3.3v to power the shift registers and the sensors: despite the Wemos D1 Mini accepts 5v digital input, sometimes a LOW input is higher than 1-1.5v therefore the Wemos D1 Mini sees it as HIGH.

The solution was to:

1. Connect to ground all unused pins (except Qh' = complementary serial output);
2. Use the 3.3v line to power the circuit instead of the 5v line.